# Como ajustar texto em volta de uma 'div/imagem'?

Tags: html, css

Estou tendo dificuldades em ajustar um texto em uma `div` que possui outra `div` dentro da mesma, que fica no topo superior esquerdo.

Abaixo segue uma imagem que explica melhor o que estou querendo fazer, espero que possam me ajudar. Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você precisa colocar a `Div B` flutuando dentro da `Div A` e logo após você coloca o seu texto. Como neste exemplo:

```css
.principal{width: 500px; height: 500px; text-align:justify; background:#ccc; color:#000; padding:10px}
.bloco{float:left; width: 150px; height: 150px; background:#fff; margin-right:10px}
```

```html
<div class="principal">
  <div class="bloco"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vel vestibulum velit. Pellentesque eu enim purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam placerat ligula id nulla congue, vitae vulputate diam ullamcorper. Praesent a quam maximus, feugiat nulla vitae, vehicula nisi. Integer ac nibh luctus, gravida elit sed, venenatis nisl. Integer suscipit metus ut volutpat dictum. Duis vestibulum sodales dictum. Ut sed felis a risus blandit facilisis non nec lacus. Quisque vitae vestibulum erat. Morbi iaculis lectus ut suscipit sagittis. Nunc cursus neque non leo venenatis, sit amet condimentum nibh molestie. Sed tortor nisl, tempor quis semper a, molestie sed nisi. Nam arcu sem, semper varius leo a, posuere maximus magna. Phasellus facilisis, velit vitae porta interdum, nisi massa auctor est, et accumsan elit quam nec elit. Pellentesque turpis dolor, varius vel sem vel, malesuada maximus eros.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi rutrum ex quis molestie pulvinar. Morbi laoreet nibh non sem venenatis hendrerit. Pellentesque augue turpis, hendrerit id lorem in, dignissim cursus lacus. Nulla quis porttitor est. Curabitur posuere et odio eu cursus. Integer sagittis, libero sit amet feugiat mattis, odio tortor cursus odio, id bibendum enim magna in urna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi porttitor sapien eget elit porttitor, a rhoncus tortor scelerisque. Pellentesque egestas leo dictum felis aliquet, vel semper sapien interdum. Etiam sed ex molestie, placerat ipsum sed, venenatis ex.
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi, eu estava tentando ajustar isso com o `postion:absolute;`, que não estava dando certo. Obrigado.

Comment: Neste caso, se você usar `postion:absolute` esta propriedade vai ignorar a propriedade `float`. Você pode ler mais sobre a propriedade `float` [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp).